# Predicting new (unknown) sequence values using aforge GA

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, aforge

I've been messing around with the aforge time series genetic algorithm sample and I've got my own version working, atm it's just 'predicting' Fibonacci numbers.

The problem is when I ask it to predict new values beyond the array I've given it (which contains the first 21 numbers of the sequence, using a window size of 5) it won't do it, it throws an exception that says "Data size should be enough for window and prediction".

As far as I can tell I'm supposed to decipher the bizarre formula contained in "population.BestChromosome" and use that to extrapolate future values, is that right? Is there an easier way? Am I overlooking something massively obvious?

I'd ask on the aforge forum but the developer is not supporting it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can tell I'm supposed to decipher the bizarre formula
>   contained in "population.BestChromosome" and use that to extrapolate
>   future values, is that right?

What you call a "bizarre formula" is called a *model* in data analysis. You learn such a model from past data and you can feed it new data to get a predicted outcome. Whether that new outcome makes sense or is just garbage depends on how general your model is. Many techniques can learn very good models that explain the observed data very well, but which are not generalizable and will return unuseful results when you feed new data into the model. You need to find a model that both explains the given data as well as potentially unobserved data which is a non-trivial process. Usually people estimate the *generalization error* of that model by splitting the known data into two partitions: one with which the model is learned and another one on which the learned models are tested. You then want to select that model which is accurate on both data. You can also check out the answer I gave on another question here which also treats the topic of machine learning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764893/189767

I don't think you're "overlooking something massively obvious", but rather you're faced with a problem that is not trivial to solve.

Btw, you can also use genetic programming (GP) in [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). The model of GP is a mathematical formula and in HeuristicLab you can export that model to e.g. MatLab.

Ad Fibonacci, the closed formula for Fibonacci numbers is F(n) = (phi^n - psi^n) / sqrt(5) where phi and psi are special magic numbers according to wikipedia. If you want to find that with GP you need one variable (n), three constants, and the power function. However, it's very likely that you find a vastly different formula that is similar in output. The problem in machine learning is that very different models can produce the same output. The recursive form requires that you include the values of the past two n into the data set. This is similar to learning a model for a time series regression problem.

Comment: After some digging the formula is in polish notation, there is an included method to 'evaluate' such formulas, so maybe I can feed it back to itself and add the variables as needed. I suppose the problem in the real world is that you don't know how many or which variables are going to be required in advance. Heuristic lab is no value to me, my data isn't static or predictable, it needs to be evaluated in real time, an external application is of no use unfortunately.

Comment: If that's a requirement then you should state it in the question.